# QGIS 3.14 Python error when executing Clip raster by extent tool

Tags: qgis, python

I am not proficient in Python, therefore I am not able to parse the error message or understand it. I am trying to clip a DEM (raster, .asc format) by the extent of town boundaries (vector). Fortunately, I can do this with FME without a problem.

```
Input parameters:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'W:/xxx', 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PROJWIN' : '977760.940000000,986582.310000000,6262610.720000000,6273061.720000000 [EPSG:2154]' }

GDAL command:
gdal_translate -projwin 977760.94 6273061.72 986582.31 6262610.72 -of GTiff W:/xxx/Dpt_83_asc.asc C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_gHDFAW/c7c4be4bb5c34603a7ed682f43cbae6c/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 138, in processAlgorithm
GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 108, in runGdal
for line in proc.stdout:
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.14\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 68: invalid start byte

Execution failed after 0.81 seconds
```

Comment: Maybe you can check this out https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31023 ? In which language is your system?

Comment: my system is in French